# Validate XDocument against a particular schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument file that I have loaded. (confirmed the working). I need to validate this document. To do so I have an XSD file that I attached to the project as a embedded resource. I load 
the xsd with these line of code:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
 Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Project.Models.Ci.def.xsd");
```

How can I now validate the XML against this XSD? I only need to know if the document is valid or not, so nothing fancy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a Validate extension method that might meet your needs.  Take a look at this documentation on MSDN - it has sample code as well:

[Extensions.Validate Method (XDocument, XmlSchemaSet, ValidationEventHandler, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354954.aspx)

Comment: doc1.Validate(schemas, (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            errors = true;
        }, true);